# Sequences in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A $ be an operator acting on an infinite dimensional  complex Hibert space $ H $. Let $W(A)$ be
 the set  of all  $\langle Ax,x \rangle $  with $x\in H,~\Vert x  \Vert=1$  and
$ w(A)=\displaystyle \sup_{z\in W(A)}\vert z\vert. $
Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence of unit vectors in $H$ such that $$ \displaystyle \lim_{n}\vert\langle Ax_{n},x_{n}  \rangle\vert=w(A).$$ Does  exist  a sequence $(y_{n})$ of unit vectors in $H$  such that 
$ \langle x_{n} , y_{n}  \rangle=0 $ for all $n$ and 
$$  \displaystyle \lim_{n}\vert \langle Ay_{n},y_{n}  \rangle\vert= w(A)?$$
Our approach is based on the following. By the Berberian-Orland trick, 
 there exist  a complex Hilbert space $K \supset H $ and an operator $A^{o}$ acting on $K$ with $A^{o}_{\vert{H}}=A$ and $W(A^{o})=adh(W(A))$, so  we have $w(A)=w(A^{o})$.
Put $$ \displaystyle \lim_{n}\langle Ax_{n},x_{n} \rangle=\langle A^{o}x,x \rangle_{K} \quad and \quad \displaystyle \lim_{n}\langle Ay_{n},y_{n} \rangle=\langle A^{o}y,y   \rangle_{K}, $$ with $x\in K$,  $y\in K$ and $\Vert x \Vert_{K}=\Vert y\Vert_{K}=1$. Therefore, it suffices to show that $\langle x,y  \rangle_{K}=0$. 
If it is the case, since   $\langle A^{o}x,x \rangle \in W(A^{o})\cap \partial W(A^{o}) $, then  we get $\vert\langle A^{o}x,x \rangle_{K}\vert=\vert\langle A^{o}y,y \rangle_{K}\vert$. That is $ \displaystyle \lim_{n}\vert\langle Ay_{n},y_{n} \rangle\vert=w(A)$.

Comment: Where is the question? Is this a "proof verification" question?

Comment: Might be stupid consideration, but in the simplest case i was able to immagine $A : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $A(z) = 2z$ this should be impossible because there are no couple of ortogonal vector with unitary norm

Comment: We ask if the sequence $(y_{n})$ exists!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Take $H=l^2$, define
$$
Ax = x_1e_1,
$$
then $\langle Ax,x\rangle = |x_1|^2$. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of unit vectors such that $\langle Ax_n,x_n\rangle \to 1$, which implies $|x_{n,1}|\to 1$.
Since $\|x_n\|=1$, it follows $\|x_n -x_{n,1}e_1\|\to0$. Let $(y_n)$ be another sequence with these properties. Then clearly $|\langle x_n,y_n\rangle|\to1$:
$$
\langle x_n,y_n\rangle = x_{n,1}y_{n,1} +\langle x_n -x_{n,1}e_1,x_n -x_{n,1}e_1\rangle,
$$
which converges to a limit with absolute value $1$, as the second addend is the inner product of two sequences converging to zero.

Comment: Why $ |\langle x_n,y_n\rangle|\to1$? to have $\langle x,y  \rangle_{K}=0 $ in my suggestion is a sufficient condition not necessary.